# Dynamically Creating Multiple TextViews in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to create multiple `TextView`s inside a `LinearLayout`.The following code builds successfully but gives a `NullPointerException`  at the line `root.addView(t[i]);`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView t[];
    LinearLayout root;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        root=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.master);
        t=new TextView[10];
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            t[i]=new TextView(this);
            t[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
            t[i].setText("YOHOHO: "+i);
            root.addView(t[i]);
        }
        setContentView(root);
    }
```

This really has no aim Iam just trying to learn things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's giving NPE because you are not setting your activity layout properly.

Do this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whereLinearLayoutMasterIs); // Add your layout here
    root=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.master);
    t=new TextView[10];
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams dim=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        t[i]=new TextView(this);
        t[i].setLayoutParams(dim);
        t[i].setText("YOHOHO: "+i);
        root.addView(t[i]);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**`R.layout.whereLinearLayoutMasterIs` is indicative, use your layout in which `R.id.master` is

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `root` is null - this is because you've not yet set your Activity's content view via `setContentView`.
You need to do something like this:

`super.onCreate(...);
setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutName);
root=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.master);`