# android- Appending textView objects to a LinearLayout by clicking on a button from a different page (multiple times)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have two Activities. Activity 1 is designed to take in user input (EditText), and has a button that (if clicked) will go to activity 2. In activity 2, there is a LinearLayout and a button that will take you back to activity 1. I can currently add one textView (containing the user input from activity 1) to the LinearLayout in activity 2, but I would like to add several textView objects to the LinearLayout. When I try to add user input any time after the first, it simply replaces the textView object that held the information from the user input that was entered the first time.

**From Activity 1 (AddExercise):**

```
public class AddExercise extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText name;
    private EditText weight;
    private EditText sets;
    private EditText reps;
    private String deets;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_exercise);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToAddWorkout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToAddWorkout() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddWorkout.class);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        sets = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sets);
        reps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reps);
        deets = name.getText().toString() + "\n\t\tWeight: " + weight.getText().toString() + "\n\t\tSets: " + sets.getText().toString() + "\n\t\tReps: " + reps.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("details", deets);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**From Activity 2 (AddWorkout):**

```
public class AddWorkout extends AppCompactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_workout);
        LinearLayout vBox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.vBox);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(extras.getString("details").toString());
            vBox.addView(tv);
        }
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToAddExercise();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a public static List of String  each time you can add your text to list and then On your second activity create text-view as per your list count. And add to your linear-layout.
[For more click here....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989079/dynamically-creating-multiple-textviews-in-linearlayout)

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like that as said by roshan-

```
((ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).insert(data_object, index);
((ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

use a shared preference for index... every time you come to second activity increment the index... on exit of app just clear the shared pref index variable.
Also you can add textview in your each list view item

Comment: Why use a Preference? Will a WeakeReference HashMap do it more robust? Just a suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to add multiple entries in your second activity, for every time you add one in the first. I would recommend a different and easier approach.

In your second activity, use a listview/recyclerview, instead of adding new textview. This has the added advantage that once you have added enough entries, scrolling won't be an issue.

Maintain a global list of entries, which you add the entries to. And populate the listview using this list.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways to do it according to me, pick the one that suits your relevant application.

1. have a single activity and host two fragments. So you can share the data between the fragments using single activity. (Recommended way, I guess Fragments will ease the job for you.). Also you can store a local variable in Activity so that each time you start your application you can start it afresh, if its intended!
2. If not, you can use SharedPreferences. For each button click, add a string to the preference. When you add one more click, append the new data with a separator like ("|", "||").. So in Activity one write to the preference, in activity 2 read from the preference and display it as list view of dynamically create the linear layout and append it to the root layout.
3. Declare a static ArrayList in your Activity 1 and access it in activity 2. (Really bad way)

Comment: Declaring a static and accessing it another Activity is not proper way. There are ways to do it. Either you can put that data into an Intent and send it to the activity, and access it later there.
Also, later if you wish to kill the Activity 1 after you move to Activity 2, this wont help!