# i am developing meme create application . generating text view Programmatically.. i can't get text of previous generated text view

Tags: java, android, textview

I am developing meme create application and generating text view Programmatically. If i generate 2 text views programmatically always i can get text of last generated text view. I can't get text of previous generated text view. How can I get text of which I on click  text view .

// Create TextView programmatically.

```
textView = new StickerTextView(MainActivity.this);
textView.setText(edt.getText().toString());
textView.setTextSize(1000);

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (popupWindow !=null)
        {
            popupclose();
        }

        text = "";

        text = textView.getText().toString();
            popupwindow(v);
    }
});

public void popupwindow(View v) {

    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvasView);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_action2,null);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageButton btnClose = (ImageButton)popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_close);

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //popupWindow.dismiss();
            popupclose();
        }
    });

    Button btntext = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.btnone);

    btntext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            showEditDialog1();


        }
    });

 public void showEditDialog1() {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        edt1 = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        edt1.setText(text);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>EDIT TEXT </font>"));
        //dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFFFF'>Done</font>"), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


        // Create TextView programmatically.
        textView.setText("");
        textView.setText(edt1.getText().toString());

        textView.setTextSize(1000);


        textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    status = START_DRAGGING;
                    final float x = me.getX();
                    final float y = me.getY();
                    lastXAxis = x;
                    lastYAxis = y;
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    status = STOP_DRAGGING;
                    flag = 0;
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
                        flag = 1;
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        final float x = me.getX();
                        final float y = me.getY();
                        final float dx = x - lastXAxis;
                        final float dy = y - lastYAxis;
                        xAxis += dx;
                        yAxis += dy;
                        v.setX((int) xAxis);
                        v.setY((int) yAxis);
                        v.invalidate();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Add TextView to LinearLayout
        if (canvas != null && textView == null) {
            canvas.addView(textView);
        }

        hidekeypad(MainActivity.this);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are using same instance variable for `TextView` each time this will override the last one .

Comment: can u give me sample code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989079/dynamically-creating-multiple-textviews-in-linearlayout

Comment: Khein Htoo if i update text of previus text view is updating last generated textb view please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should get the value from argument(view v) which is passed via onClick override function of onClickLisenter interface. And because you are using `StickerTextView` then:

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (popupWindow !=null)
                    {
                        popupclose();
                    }

                    text = "";

                    text = ((StickerTextView)v).getText().toString();


                        popupwindow(v);



                }
```

Comment: if i update text of previews text view is updating last generated text view please help me –

Comment: Dear Sir How can Update Text of which Textview I get text

Comment: argument(v) is the text view that you clicked, which means that you can cast it to text view and update it using setText().